# How to make your game character move accordingly?

Tags: haskell, input, functional-programming, ncurses

I'm currently trying to create a snake-like game in haskell using hscurses in the terminal, and I'm having a bit of trouble implementing the input-functionality of the game. My problem is that whenever I hold down one of the movement keys, for example 'a', the character moves to the left for as many characters that were registered by the console. This leads to when I want to switch directions, for example down by pressing 's', the character keeps on moving to the left and the down-movement gets delayed.

```
res :: Int -> IO a -> IO (Maybe a)
res n f = concurrently (System.Timeout.timeout n f) (threadDelay n) >>= \(result, _) -> return 
result

getInput :: IO Char
getInput = hSetEcho stdin False 
>> hSetBuffering stdin NoBuffering
>> getChar
```

and the part of the main game-loop function that handles the input:

```
loop :: Window -> State -> Player -> IO State
loop window state player = do
    threadDelay 1000000
    k <- res 100 getInput
    newState <- updateState player state
    newPlayer <- movePlayer player k
    render newState newPlayer window
```

and the movePlayer function:

```
movePlayer :: Player -> Maybe Char -> IO Player
movePlayer Player {xy=xy1, direction = d} k =
    case k of
        Just 'w' -> return Player {xy = (fst xy1, snd xy1-1), direction = Up}
        Just 's' -> return Player {xy = (fst xy1, snd xy1+1), direction = Downie}
        Just 'd' -> return Player {xy = (fst xy1+1, snd xy1), direction = Rightie}
        Just 'a' -> return Player {xy = (fst xy1-1, snd xy1), direction = Leftie}
        Nothing -> return Player {xy = addVecs xy1 (dirToVec d), direction = d}
        _ -> return Player {xy = xy1, direction = d}
```

I can't figure out what the problem is, so any help is appreciated or if there's another method of implementing this input-functionality

Answer (score 1):

Currently your input loop and your state update loop are tied together: there's always at most one input accepted per update. You will need to desynch them.

The low-tech alternative is to change the spot you currently have `res 100 getInput` to actually run `getInput` in a loop, and only keep the last `Char` it receives before blocking. The medium-tech alternative is to have two threads, one for reading input and one for doing state updates, with a shared `MVar` or similar saying what key was pressed last. The high-tech alternative is to use a library like [brick](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/brick) to handle all of your input and output.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Could you perhaps elaborate a bit more on the low-tech alternative? how am I to run res 100 getInput in a loop other than in the main loop-function, and how do I only keep the last Char before blocking the input? I'm pretty new to haskell, so I'm sorry if this seems obvious. @DanielWagner

Comment: @EyedBread Something like `flushInput k = do { k' <- res 100 getInput; case k' of Nothing -> pure k; Just _ -> flushInput k' }`, which can be called with `Nothing` to get things kicked off.